# How do I add custom order fields for users to fill out at checkout

Tags: commerce

Drupal 7 - Commerce

I have 2 fields related to the order. one is radio button where user selects Pickup, Delivery. the other one I won't mention as it might confuse some people. I want the user to select which one they want at checkout. How do I do this?

I've added the fields the order. admin/commerce/config/order/fields. They don't show up on the checkout, but they do show up when the admin tries to edit the order.

I tried setting the fields as required, but the order gets created with these fields blank (this is a bug).

There are no options to add these fields on Checkout Settings admin/commerce/config/checkout.

I am not looking to add fields inside Billing Information nor Shipping Information.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem using [Commerce Field Group](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_fieldgroup_panes).   What you do is:

- create the fields you want.
- create the field group.
- put the new fields inside the field group.

Then

- goto the Checkout Settings (admin/commerce/config/checkout) and add the group inside `Review`

Comment: This answer is correct, and here is a video of exactly how to make it work: https://commerceguys.com/blog/commerce-module-tuesday-commerce-fieldgroup-panes-screencast.

Comment: How to add ajax callbacks to these fileds inside fieldgroup ?