# How do I add a custom textarea into the checkout screen?

Tags: 8, commerce

I want to add 'Notes' textarea for adding addtional message by customer while placing the order.

I have added additional textarea in 'Order types' page (/admin/commerce/config/order-types/default/edit/fields). It is displaying in order page but not in checkout page.

Example: Customer is placing an order for Toys and they want to add message saying 'Please deliver in 2 days..'

Edit: I have seen [same question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9035/how-do-i-add-custom-order-fields-for-users-to-fill-out-at-checkout?rq=1) in Drupal 7. But there is no '[Commerce Fieldgroup Panes](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_fieldgroup_panes)' module in Drupal 8.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to write a custom checkout pane plugin, I'm afraid.

Docs here: https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/checkout/create-custom-checkout-pane

Comment: I'm able to add the textarea using using '$pane_form['customer_message'] = array( '#type' => 'textarea', '#title' => t('Customer Message:'), );' and not sure where it is storing and how I can get this message into order page.

Answer (score -1):

You can add custom fields using profile > Customer by following path.

```
/admin/config/people/profiles/manage/customer/fields
```

You must have installed [Profile](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile) module also with [Commerce 2](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce)